# Display Cms Document Community site

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-experience, pdf, salesforce-cms

**Context:**

On a community site I have a requirement to display specific CMS. A lightning component call an apex function to get specific CMS using the function function  [ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getManagedContentByTopics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ManagedContent_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ManagedContent_getManagedContentByTopics_4) .
It return list of ManagedContent, here is one of them:
[image]

**Question**:

The need is to display this cms document which is a PDF in an aura component/LWC
I tried to put the contentNodes.source.url in an IFrame but it directly downloads the pdf without preview.

How can I display this pdf on my custom component?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? How do show the document?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I displayed the pdf:

Aura:

```
<iframe src="{!v.docUrl}" width="100%" height="1000px;" scroll="yes" frameBorder="0" />
```

JS:

```
component.set("v.docUrl", '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/' + selectedContentKey );
```